# Dynamic creation and selection of html elements via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

How can I access the dynamically created html element by its Id on very next line of this following code?

```
var line = $('<div class="showInGrid" id="removeMeLater">
              <span class="dateP" id="calendar' + ind + '" ></span>
              </div>');
```

**I want to access it like the following line of code.**

```
$("#calendar"+ind).datepicker({});
```

However I'm able to link the datepicker with it like the following.

```
line.datepicker({});
```

But obviously it is not giving me the desired result and it gets created every time loop iterates over it.

Comment: In this case, I think we need to see more of your code. You mention a loop. How about showing us the relevant code for that. Otherwise, just what you provided (and your comment on CerlinBoss's answer) looks like it should work.

Comment: @Philtune If you are interested I have setup a jsbin and I can share it in person. I don't have plans to open it up publicly yet. As this will go as my first blog post ever :) That's why just hiding it yet. Will you be interested in giving it a go?

Comment: Honestly, no. And that's just because I want to encourage and help you to create good questions on SO. (Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and bookmark it if you use this site a lot.) Your question is likely to be of benefit to others who might google this, so (as that link recommends) try to create a **minimal** yet **complete** and **verifiable** example so users can replicate your issue. (Otherwise, I'd recommend asking your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.) This process often ends up helping you to solve the problem yourself. If not, it certainly helps us help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not added the element to the DOM.

jquery selector will search inside the DOM. since the element is not in DOM it will return an empty array.

run `$("#calendar"+ind).datepicker({});` after appending it to the body

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned that but I added it with this line.

    $('#myCalendar').append(line);

Comment: so after `$('#myCalendar').append(line);` you can use `$("#calendar"+ind).datepicker({});`